# Kernel of tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

> Let $F_n=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2^n})$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $I_n$ be
>    the kernel of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \otimes_\mathbb{Q}
>  \overline{\mathbb{Q}} \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}} \otimes_{F_n}
> \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, by $u \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} v \mapsto u
>  \otimes_{F_n} v$. Show that $I_n \subset I_{n+1}$

We have $F_0 \subset F_1 \subset ...$. Let $u,v \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that $u\otimes_{F_n} v =0$, how can we show that $u \otimes_{F_{n+1}} v =0$?

Does the following diagram commute?
$$\begin{array}{c} & A \otimes_F B & \\  & \swarrow  ~~~~~~~ \searrow  \\ A \otimes_{F_n} B & \rightarrow & A \otimes_{F_m} B. \end{array}$$

Comment: I'm missing something: why does $u \otimes_{F_n}v = 0 \implies u \otimes_{F_{n+1}} v = 0$ tell you that your diagram commutes?

Comment: Oh sorry. The commutative diagram would imply the $I_n \subset I_{n+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the universal property, $u \otimes_{F_n} v = 0$ if and only if for every $F_n$-bilinear map $\phi:\bar {\Bbb Q} \times \bar{\Bbb Q} \to \Bbb F_n$, we have $\phi(u,v) = 0$.  Note, however, that an $F_{n+1}$-bilinear map must also be $F_{n}$-bilinear.

We could also apply this reasoning to answer your original question directly, since an element $\sum_i u_i \otimes_{F_n} v_i$ is zero if and only if for every $F_n$-bilinear map $\phi$ to $F_n$, we have $\sum_i F(u_i,v_i) = 0$.